# Thue's proof of finitely many integer solutions to $x^2 - y^3 = c$

Tags: number-theory

I believe I read somewhere that a mathematician named Thue in 1902 proved that the equation $x^2 - y^3 = c$ has only finitely many integer solutions for nonzero integer $c$.

Does anyone know where I can find the original paper or an exposition of his original proof?

I am interested in looking up the proof since it was proved early before many advanced algebraic machinery I was wondering if I could study his original proof and understand it since my background is very modest.

Comment: The original proof appears here:  Thue, A. "Über Annäherungswerte algebraischer Zahlen." J. reine angew. Math. 135, 284-305, 1909.  [here](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0135?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B288%5D%7D) is a link to the article itself (which, of course, is in German).

Comment: And [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X89900140) is a more modern paper, in English, which contains effective bounds on the solution.

Comment: I should say:  for the most part, modern algebraic language and machinery make these things a lot easier to approach.  Any paper from 1909, in whatever language, is going to pose a whole lot of challenges for the reader...my advice (for whatever it's worth) is to start with modern papers and then go back if you want to get insight into older methodologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original paper can be found [at this link](https://eudml.org/doc/149305).